# Accidental deletion of the System32 files in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, ms-dos, recovery

I accidentally executed the following command in `cmd` with administrative privilages in my `c:\windows\system32` folder:

```
del *.* /f/q/s > nul
```

When I realized what was happening I quickly pressed `Ctrl+C` to cancel the operation. In the meantime I got a bunch of `Access is denied.` errors.

How do I know if I have or have not caused any damage to my Windows installation? Is there a way to check it? Can I just delete files from the `system32` folder or they're protected?

In case if I have caused damage, can I repair my Windows installation without restoring it to a previous state?

I know that the `del` command doesn't send the deleted file to Recycle Bin, hence I have no way of checking if anything has been deleted.

Comment: There are Windows state validation and Windows repair functions. Have you tried these?

Comment: if it's gone, it's gone. The best thing you can do is `sfc /scannow`

Comment: @music2myear can you please tell me how to run those functions?

Comment: Why would you run that command in the first place, somebody play a trick on you?

Comment: @Moab, I had changed the directory using ```cd```, but the new directory was on my ```D``` drive and ```cmd.exe``` had launched under ```c:\windows\system32```. So I ran the ```del``` command before changing the drive to ```D```.

Comment: Web search is your friend and will tell you how to scan your OS for validation and repair functions both.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP hasn't indicated an actual issue, just concern they MIGHT have caused an issue.

Comment: Below is a link to a Microsoft webpage that in details describes what commands to run in order to repair your current Windows installation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e It also includes @phuclv's suggestion ```sfc /scannow```. Here is what I got in response when I ran that command: *Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them. For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example